# Retrieving photos from Firebase in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, firebase, ionic3

I'm developing an Ionic 3 phone wallpapers application and I'm using Firebase database for uploading photos now I'm trying to show this photos in the app

Like I upload 3 photos (1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg) I write this code to get them from the database.

```
 imageSource;
 photo;



 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.imageSource = (1);
    this.getPhotoURL();
  }

  getPhotoURL() {
    firebase.storage().ref().child('/' + this.imageSource + '.jpg').getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      this.photo = url;
    })
  }
```

and in HTML I have this

```
<ion-col>
     <img src="{{photo}}">
</ion-col>
```

But can only get the photo name i write in `.|| this.imageSource = (1);" ||.`
and every time I want to get a new photo I have to make a new function.

So how can I get an automatic update for any photo I upload 
or I need a better code that can give me the 3 photos with an easy way to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the file, you have to get the downloadURL with uploadTask.snapshot.downloadedURL and save it, like this

```
public downloadedUrls: [];

var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/rivers.jpg').put(file);

// Register three observers:
// 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
// 2. Error observer, called on failure
// 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){

  // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
  // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
  var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
  console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
  switch (snapshot.state) {
    case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
      console.log('Upload is paused');
      break;
    case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
      console.log('Upload is running');
      break;
  }
}, function(error) {
  // Handle unsuccessful uploads
}, function() {
  // Handle successful uploads on complete
  // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
  this.downloadedUrls.push(uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL);
});
```

With downloadedUR, you can save in an array, for example, and then, you can loop this array in html with all url's from the saved images, like this:

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let photo of downloadedUrls">
   <img src="{{ photo }}">
</ion-col>
```

where downloadedUrls can be a string array, for example. I made myself understood?

Hope it helps.

Ps: the upload method I get from Firebase Storage Docs, you can check it

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files?hl=pt-br

Comment: i don't need to upload any thing i just want to show my photos

Comment: Yes, but to show your photo you have to download, right? To download, at some moment, you had uploaded, or not?

Comment: Its worth trying